# Velosity, speed and acceleration for particle motion?

Tags: calculus, vectors

The position is 
$\mathbf{x}(t) = \frac12t^2 \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{u} t + \mathbf{d}$,
where $t^2 \in [0,\infty)$ and $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{d}$ are constant vectors.

Find velocity, speed and acceleration?

Could you help me with this? I am not sure how do I differentiate **x**(t) when I have constant vectors.

Is the velocity **v** = t **a** + **u**?

Comment: Yes. Your are correct. Just to be picky, but i would also state that $x$ is also a vector i.e. use $\mathbf{x}(t)$ :).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. In general, you just differentiate the components of the vector.

When the vectors contain constants, you just treat the vectors like any other constant. So, e.g,

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}{1 \\2}\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}{\frac{d}{dt}1 \\\frac{d}{dt}2}\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}{0 \\0}\end{bmatrix}$$

When the vectors contain functions of the variable you're differentiating w.r.t., you differentiate them. E.g.,

$$ \frac{d}{dt}t^2\begin{bmatrix}{1 \\2}\end{bmatrix}
= \frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}{t^2 \\2t^2}\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}{\frac{d}{dt}t^2 \\\frac{d}{dt}2t^2}\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}{2t \\4t}\end{bmatrix}
= 2t\begin{bmatrix}{1 \\2}\end{bmatrix}$$

in the last case, you can see that because the vector itself is constant you can just differentiate the $t^2$ outside of the vector and treat the vector just like a regular constant in a scalar equation. So you could have jumped straight to the last step.

Comment: If we have for example x(t) =(**i** sin q(t) cos f(t) + **j** sin q(t) sin f(t) + **k** cos q(t)) , where q(t) and f(t) are scalar functions, how we find the velocity? Is it equal to derivative of q(t) * cos(q(t)) **i** +( derivative of q(t)*cos(g(t)) sin(f(t)) + sin(q(t))* derivative of f(t) * cos(f(t))) **j ** -  **k**  *derivative of q(t) * sin(q(t))

Comment: Hi, as **i**, **j**, **k** are all constant vectors, then it's $a'(t)\mathbf{i} + b'(t)\mathbf{j} + c'(t)\mathbf{k}$, where $a(t)=\sin q(t) \cos f(t),\; b(t)=\sin q(t) \sin f(t),\; c(t)=\cos  q(t)$, and the $'$ means take the derivative. Hth

Comment: x(t) = R (i sin q(t) cos f(t) + j sin q(t) sin f(t) + k cos q(t)) what actually is this? What is the discribtion of this motion? R is a constant greater than 0 and i,j,k are the standart basis.

Comment: @user2013804 sorry I'm not sure where this is going, it seems like a different question from your first one, and is hard to deal with in comments. Your function x(t) has each of its distances in the x(i), y(j) and z(k) directions described by the appropriate functions of t.

Comment: I just have to solve a lot of this type of problems. :)  Can't understant what the last one is, that is why I am asking here:)